# How to construct a class with variadic pointer functions as members?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I want to know whether the following is possible in C++. I need to construct a class that will store as a data member a `std::map`, with keys being of type `std::string`, and values being function pointers. The thing is that I want these function pointers to be variadic in the sense that they should point to functions accepting an arbitrary number of arguments, i.e. pointing to functions of the form

`template<class... Args>
f(Args...);`

The important bit is that I want to be able to have different arguments for the different function pointers in the map of a given instance of my class. For example, I might want to create an object of my class and have its map contain two pairs, one corresponding to a function having `(double, int)` as arguments, and another having `(std::vector, int, int)` as arguments. And I want to be able to make this general, in the sense that I want to be able to add new elements to the map, with possibly different argument lists (although I would only do this at compile-time, I still need to code the class without knowing about the types since I want to add the new elements from other files/clients).

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: How would you call functions from that map? Most solution would drop any kind of compile-time type safety. Can you use `std::any` to store your function pointers?

Comment: Sounds like a job for type erasure.

Comment: Once you turn `f` into a function pointer it is a concrete function with a fixed number of parameters and types. You cannot store a template.

Comment: A map does not seem the best container for what you are trying to do. If the universe of function is finite and small, perhaps you should consider just using a struct.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I would call them from within another method of the class. To put it in context, I am trying to use a factory to create objects of a certain hierarchy, whose constructors may accept different types of arguments. This hierarchy can be expanded in the future, hence why I need the generality. The function pointers are the creator functions which return new objects of the given type

Comment: All your values must be of the same type. A template is not a type, and its instantiations have different types.

Answer (score 0):

For all those saying you cant, you actually can, it's not pretty:

This is an example code from the output of the moc tool, that does exactly that: It stores an arbitrary amount of function / method pointers, with an arbitrary number of arguments.

Easiest Solution: Just use Qt's moc tool to generate that for you,
If you cannot or don't want to use Qt, you still can analize the code below on how they achieve it.

```
int AtCore::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    _id = QObject::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
    if (_id < 0)
        return _id;
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        if (_id < 25)
            qt_static_metacall(this, _c, _id, _a);
        _id -= 25;
    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::RegisterMethodArgumentMetaType) {
        if (_id < 25)
            *reinterpret_cast<int*>(_a[0]) = -1;
        _id -= 25;
    }
    return _id;
}


void AtCore::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        AtCore *_t = static_cast<AtCore *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->printProgressChanged((*reinterpret_cast< const float(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 1: _t->receivedMessage((*reinterpret_cast< const QByteArray(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 2: _t->stateChanged((*reinterpret_cast< PrinterState(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 3: _t->print((*reinterpret_cast< const QString(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 4: _t->stop(); break;
        case 5: _t->pause((*reinterpret_cast< const QString(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 6: _t->resume(); break;
        case 7: _t->home((*reinterpret_cast< uchar(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 8: _t->home(); break;
        case 9: _t->setExtruderTemp((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1])),(*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[2]))); break;
        case 10: _t->setExtruderTemp((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 11: _t->setExtruderTemp(); break;
        case 12: _t->move((*reinterpret_cast< uchar(*)>(_a[1])),(*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[2]))); break;
        case 13: _t->setBedTemp((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 14: _t->setBedTemp(); break;
        case 15: _t->setFanSpeed((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1])),(*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[2]))); break;
        case 16: _t->setFanSpeed((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 17: _t->setFanSpeed(); break;
        case 18: _t->setAbsolutePosition(); break;
        case 19: _t->setRelativePosition(); break;
        case 20: _t->setPrinterSpeed((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 21: _t->setPrinterSpeed(); break;
        case 22: _t->setFlowRate((*reinterpret_cast< uint(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 23: _t->setFlowRate(); break;
        case 24: _t->close(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod) {
        int *result = reinterpret_cast<int *>(_a[0]);
        void **func = reinterpret_cast<void **>(_a[1]);
        {
            typedef void (AtCore::*_t)(const float & );
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&AtCore::printProgressChanged)) {
                *result = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        {
            typedef void (AtCore::*_t)(const QByteArray & );
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&AtCore::receivedMessage)) {
                *result = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        {
            typedef void (AtCore::*_t)(PrinterState );
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&AtCore::stateChanged)) {
                *result = 2;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```